# Loop not generated when using promise in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this function

```
handleFileInput(file: any) {  
      let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.uploadFileDetails.push({ filename:this.FileName,filetype:this.FileType});
      ...
       resolve(data.Location);
      return promise;
}
```

when i loop through `this.uploadFileDetails` i get error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

```
   <div *ngFor="let fileDetails of uploadFileDetails">

    </div>
```

but when i remove this loop then i can see the values being saved properly.

Any solution Thanks

Comment: Where and how have you initialized `this.uploadFileDetails`? The error is quite clear: `this.uploadFileDetails` is `undefined`

Comment: @derpirscher io have already initialized it   `uploadFileDetails:any=[];` the error is due to promise i think, when i remove html code then the code is working fine because the current code upload the file on aws server and it takes time

Comment: @derpirscher I tried to use `<ng-container *ngIf="(uploadFileDetails | async).length">` also in my component this is not working, in my case loop is running before the value is being saved in the `this.uploadedFileDetails`

Comment: @derpirscher is correct though. The error is very clear. Somewhere in your code `uploadFileDetails` is being set to `undefined`.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner because data is loading with some delay `this.FileName` and `this.FileType` these variables are undefined that's why getting error

Comment: @user3653474 No. The error is specifically talking about about *"reading `push`"*. And the only thing where you try to read `push` from (at least in the code you are showing) is `this.uploadFileDetails.push(..)`. The values of `this.FileName` or `this.FileType` are irrelevant for this error. I don't know what happens in the rest of your project. But in this very moment, for sure `this.uploadFileDetails` is `undefined`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try this solution, I guess issues with scope of variables in Promise respons

```
handleFileInput(file: any) { 
    var that = this; <--- add this line
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        that.uploadFileDetails.push({ filename:that.FileName,filetype:that.FileType});
        ...
        resolve(data.Location);
        return promise;        
    }
}
```